# How to get generic? class from json response? If one object can contain many different classes

Tags: java, generics, types, jsonresponse, typetoken

I want to extract json object with restassured, and response is generic like:

```
@Data
public class ExtractBase<T> {
    private Class<T> result; // here I can expect different classes 
    private String targetUrl;
    private Boolean success;
    private String error;
    private Boolean unAuthorizedRequest;
    private Boolean __abp;
```

}

and I want extract it and get **result** each time with different class:

```
.extract().body().as(ExtractBase.class).getResult(); // and here I want to have possibility to choose class which should be exctracted depends on my request
```

I have tried to use TypeToken but with no result :(

any tips for extracting generic classes from JSON responses?

Comment: Did you tried with type Object or Map or List for property result ? It may help

Answer (score 0):

Use ObjectMapper to map from Objects response to custom type.
Example
objectMapper.readValue(json.getBoody(), YourType.class)
Remember, that objectMaper mustbe register module on methot objectMaper

```
private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().findAndRegisterModules();
```

and your response shouldby

```
private T result;  - witout "class"
```

Comment: hmm ill try it, for now i get workaround with extending my class:

public class PostRejectHandler extends ExtractBase<PostRejectResponse>{}

and my extract base class is: 
public class ExtractBase<T> {
    private T result;
}